# Twitter Login and registration with cakephp 2.X

Tags: cakephp, twitter, components

Iam a new in cakephp 2.x platform. now iam trying to connect my application login with twitter. i get lots of tutorial from the net. but all are not specified exactly for better understanding..

i followed  this tutorial ExtAuth[enter link description here](https://github.com/sc0ttyd/ExtAuth)

i tried all the things from that tutorial..but it showing error

```
Missing argument 1 for UsersController::auth_login() [APP\Controller\UsersController.php, line 105]
```

and

```
        ExtAuth plugin of type AuthProvider not found
```

how can we load the Auth provider?
if anybody cangive a complete tutorial or example for twitter login..pleae help me..

Thanxin advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check these tutorials 
http://www.chetanvarshney.com/social-media/twitter/twitter-application-for-user-management-plugin/

https://github.com/uzyn/cakephp-opauth
works for me ......

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the instructions for Usage for ExtAuth, as specified in the readme?

Specifically, ensure that the UsersController is correctly loading the ExtAuth component?

You need this line at the top of your UsersController:

```
public $components = array('ExtAuth.ExtAuth', 'Auth', 'Session');
```